# Which Java package needs to be imported for HTTP Client?

Tags: java

I need to use following code that will fetch me Response for Http Cline request, but don't no which package will be used since i m new to java.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/humans.txt");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: The package that contains `URL` and `HttpURLConnection`. It's not hard to find. Too localized.

Comment: have you google it before asking?

Comment: @freak More to the point, has he looked it up in the Javadoc before asking? There is an alpha index. It's not difficult.

Comment: @EJP I am damn sure that OP picked up this code from Google, so I suggest him near way :D

Comment: @freak You don't have any basis for that suspicion, and in any case where he got the original code from is completely irrelevant to how he should proceed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the java.net package. Just put

```
import java.net.URL;
```

and also

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

Answer (score 1):

import `java.net.HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IDE (I can only speak for Netbeans and Eclipse but I'm sure most are the same) then it should error when you write it without an import, and when you mouse over it will give you the option to automatically import the correct class (provided it's a class built into the Java libraries or you've included the library in your classpath).

For example, in NetBeans, simply click on the line underlined in red and press Alt+Enter.

In this particular case, as others have said, you're looking to import:

```
java.net.HttpURLConnection
```